# Alarms are not working after some duration in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-alarms

```
Calendar calendars = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendars.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                        calendars.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
                        calendars.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        calendars.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                        calendars.set(Calendar.AM_PM, timezone);                        
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), currentTime, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendars.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                        } else {
                            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendars.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                        }
                    } else {                        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendars.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                    }
```

In my App if I set Alarm within an hour then it is working fine but for long duration it is not working.

I have searched a lot regarding the alarm issue we are facing and found out that in latest android updates android OS is killing the broadcast receivers if memory needed for other task OR in low battery state OR without a reason.

In some cases if mobile is in idle / doze mode that time also alarm is not working.